# How to use nuxt.js with node and expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nuxt.js

I'm making a simple signup/login API with node and express as a backend but i want to know how to use nuxt as a front to connect to my APIs endpoints so i can depoloy my node app

Comment: My suggestion is to look on youtube for tutorial - try some things out and when you get stumped post the code and errors here to get help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is, you need to move to your `nuxt.config.js` and you need to tell nuxt witch routes are for viewing content and witch are just API endpoints. For that there is a option called `serverMiddleware`

```
serverMiddleware: [
   '~/api/index.js'
],
```

Now you need to create an Folder in your root directory called `api` and inside the `api` folder there you should create an file called `index.js`, that will be your express.js server.

The index.js looks like this:

```
 const express = require('express')
 const app = express()

 app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "I work" });
 })

 module.exports = {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
 }
```

Dont forget to install express `npm i express`
After that you need to restart your server.
If you navigate now to `localhost:3000/api/test` you should see `I work`

I have also found out if you make for example a mistake, nuxt will tell you `404 cant find that page`. For example you write `const express = require("express")` but you forget to install it via `npm i express`, nuxt will just throw error `404` without saying that you dont installed express

Comment: i have also written an small blog post about it: https://blogxon.com/articles/basic-express-nuxt-api

Comment: can you add an example of how you ll test this /test route using jest?

Comment: @PirateApp here is a well written example https://dev.to/nedsoft/testing-nodejs-express-api-with-jest-and-supertest-1km6

Comment: thank you for that link, i have seen that one before, it is testing plain express which is quite simple, testing nuxt requires setup and teardown with renderer etc which is why a nuxt specific API testing example would do wonders